# node script with bash conditional based on env var

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to set up my npm script to run differently depending on the environment. I want to check if `process.env.DEPLOY_URL` exists, or not, and run separate scripts depending on this.

Right now, I have -

`"build": "if [[ -z ${DEPLOY_URL} ]]; then npm run test:integration; else webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js --colors; fi"`

However, the command line where this is being run is saying

`sh: 1: [[: not found`

This is happening when  `process.env.DEPLOY_URL` is available, so it is hitting the else when i do not want it to. I am guessing the command line that is running this does not have bash. Looking for a way to fix this - or any way to achieve this via npm script. thanks!

I was looking at something like https://github.com/ericclemmons/if-env to possibly use, but it does not have a !env.var setting as far as I can tell.

Comment: The node script is running the bourne shell `sh` which is POSIX compliant whichc does not understand `[[` which is bourne again shell specific construct

Comment: @Inian ok thank you! Could you point me to any resource on how I should approach this? Much appreciated!

Comment: Change `[[ -z ${DEPLOY_URL} ]]` to `[ -z "${DEPLOY_URL}" ]` and see if it worked

Comment: @Inian that did the trick! if you want to submit an answer I will mark as correct. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running a shell that makes use of the POSIX compliant shell `sh` in which the `[[` operator is not present. It is a `bash` specific feature. To make the script use the POSIX compliant string empty check operator use the `[` operator

```
if [ -z "${DEPLOY_URL}" ]
```